# Create multiple Text widgets on every tab

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

**What do I need**: create Text widgets on every tab.

**My code right now**:

```
    for i in range(len(result)):
        tab[i] = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tabControl.add(tab[i], text=i)
    tabControl.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        textwrite[i] = Text(tab[i])
        textwrite[i].pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        scrollbar_fortext[i] = Scrollbar(tab[i], orient='vertical', command=textwrite[i].yview)
        scrollbar_fortext[i].pack(fill='both', expand=True, sticky=NS)
```

**Expected behavior**: every tab has a Text widget.

**Received behavior**:

```
NameError: name 'textwrite' is not defined
```

Comment: In your example Text is both a tkinter `Text` widget AND a list! That's the main problem, the other is creating a `Text` widget and packing it in a single statement. Doing so will return `None`.

Comment: @Derek I modified the code, but now a new error. Please check.

Comment: The `ttk.Frames` in `tab[i]` need to be packed.

Comment: @Derek `tabControl.add(...)` will do it implicitly.

Comment: The error obviously tells you that the list variable `textwrite` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` if you want to declare dynamic variable.
As your code is not complete, I've kept len(result) as 5. Change the code according to your requirement.
The options for '-sticky' are only -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side. There is no option such as NS. So, I've removed that. Change accordingly.
This is how the code should be.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root, width=700)
tabControl.pack()

dct = {}
#for testing purpose I've given length of result as 5.Change the code accordingly.
for i in range(5):
    dct[f'tab_{i}'] = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(dct[f'tab_{i}'], text = f'{i}')
    dct[f'scrollbar_fortext_{i}'] = Scrollbar(dct[f'tab_{i}'], orient='vertical')
    dct[f'scrollbar_fortext_{i}'].pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    
    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `tab`, `textwrite` and `scrollbar_fortext` variables (preferably as empty dictionaries) before creating items with indexing. Also, you should use only one `for` loop and generate the `tab`, `textwrite` and `scrollbar_fortext`.
Use `tabControl.pack()` either before or after the for loop. It will be better if you change the variable name `tab` to something else.